# Plant identification keys dataset

Tags: identification

Where can I download (or scrape) a structured dataset (such that I could, after some initial massaging, use it in a NodeJS app for example) of plants with identification keys?

I'm looking for a dataset with the largest set of plants but I'd like to see any such dataset so I can at least start playing around.

Answer (score 2):

A website I formerly worked on, Learn2Grow.com, has licensing programs for their plant database (http://www.learn2grow.com/plants).  They might be able to help you.

Comment: I could not find anything about a plant database on the site.

Comment: I updated your post to clarify your affiliation with the site you link to. Please see the [help/behavior] for the rules on self-promotion. And as already said, there doesn't appear to be any information about licensing on that site: could you be more specific about where to find it and what the terms might be?

Comment: Clarification on the clarification, I am no longer affiliated with Learn2Grow, although I was once a software developer for them.  Left their employ about 16 months ago.  For the record, I receive no commission or other benefit from referring anyone to them.

Comment: I know I asked for contact information, but posting **someone else's** address publicly is really not OK. I was hoping for a "Contact Us" page on the website.

Comment: Mike's always been very public with that email address for company business, so I didn't have any hesitation with publishing it.  If it were his personal email address, I'd agree wholeheartedly with you.  You can find the contact link (http://learn2grow.com/Help.aspx) on the bottom of any page of that site.